# Masking my IP address when using `wget` or `curl`

Tags: ip-address, geoip

I am trying to access/download a file on an old server which has geolocation restriction. I was just wondering if I can use `wget` or `curl` on macOS and change my ip address so that the old server allows download. I know I can use VPN/Proxy but I am interested to know if there is generally a simpler way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configure your torrc file with ExitNodes using the county you wish your circuit to exit, restart Tor, then use torsocks with wget or curl.

Comment: I have tried that, but for some certain countries the circuit cannot be created. For instance `ExitNodes {us} StrictNodes 0`
works seamlessly but `ExitNodes {iq} StrictNodes 0` does not.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any ExitNodes in Iraq. https://metrics.torproject.org/rs.html#search/county:iq